# Use Autoupdating in Google Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update

I'm making an extension for Google Chrome and I use code for [autoupdating](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html). This is because the extension isn't yet in Google Chrome webstore. But in a few days I will upload it to the Webstore and Google says you can use the Webstores autoupdating. But if I don't want to use that, will my app still update by my own server, like the way it does now?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that docs are not very clear about this:

> If you publish your extension using the Chrome Developer Dashboard,
>   you can ignore this page. You can use the dashboard to release updated
>   versions of your extension to users, as well as to the Chrome Web
>   Store.

But, I've tested it myself and your `update_url` setting in `manifest.json` will be overridden when you publish your extension via Chrome Web Store (CWS). In other words, publishing to CWS means that you can't use self hosted autoupdating anymore.

The reasons for that, that I could think of, may be as follows:

- CWS wants to keep track of each extension stats (i.e. number of users using each extension)
- privacy concerns (people don't want you to track them when they update extension)
- security concerns (each extension update must go through CWS verification process)

If you want to track people (please don't) use Google Analytics on i.e. background page of your extension.